# How to make property optional when using ReturnType<>

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have this:

```
const getDefaultState = () => ({
  mainNotifMessage: '(unknown message)',
  notifDetails: '(unknown notification details)',
  severity: 'info' as 'info' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'success' | undefined,
  snackBarOpen: true,
  foo: Date.now() as any
});


export type NotifDefaultState = ReturnType<typeof getDefaultState>;
```

*How can I tell t that I want the foo property to be optional?* I tried this:

```
export type NotifDefaultState = ReturnType<typeof getDefaultState> & {ts?: any};
```

but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

You go "backwards" and loosen a type. Since you are creating the type from a concrete instance that has the key, TypeScript infers that the key must be present.

You will have to create an interface and export that.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have any built-in support for programmatically altering modifiers like `?` or `readonly` on individual keys of an object type; see [microsoft/TypeScript#32562](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32562) for a feature request.  Until such things are implemented, you can build something close yourself using the utility types [`Pick`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) and [`Omit`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk), and an [intersection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).  The following implementation of `SelectivePartial` uses a trick with [conditional type inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to make the final displayed type a single object and not an ugly intersection:

```
type SelectivePartial<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K> extends infer O ?
    { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

Then your `NotifDefaultState` could be defined like this:

```
export type NotifDefaultState = SelectivePartial<ReturnType<typeof getDefaultState>, "foo">;

/* type NotifDefaultState = {
    foo?: any;
    mainNotifMessage: string;
    notifDetails: string;
    severity: "info" | "error" | "warning" | "success" | undefined;
    snackBarOpen: boolean;
} */
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygEQQMwIYFcA2UDKUGUCMAvDABQCU5AfFQN4CwAUDBzALYYCWYAORBReaALIIIEDIgBcMAOSUsYANZgQAdzDdJ0xNQUAaNpxgaRaVEV44I8pSvVadF0b2DFe4GABMkfHaGJuycEAgAbggATrxQAJ4O-GggCjAYEIrJqTAAPoox0SDRafkKmhjRYPxwpYoQWMDAenUq-mj8CL4hZhBgGMCqAEKVAPIADghg8lDRWAg9nCkg8sjECAB0Gpo06ZkYYPFsAL7UANxsbAmTMPgIOAjAIlEACpUiGDgAPAAqRjAAaRgCAAHiQwL5MqoEPEQGgYD8GBQ3tEPt8Xh5VL9-gC6AwAGQwUZcOLYwEMUHgyEwZIxIkwAD8pk4jBgAG0XjSdNDYfDRgBdeSjDn8mDHGDyMCRGIXVhsUHjYqwa6kISWVCYXAEIgkci3e6PZ4IFFor4AJSQWCqP3iky+Krh8CQGuweEI6zo-wARMsvXRZQB6ABUMBVMDVohdWvduooLFCHGWDPkB3isrMPH4EfEehkCHk0FiYDg6c4bisAVs9hghZqpY44SisQS8i92S9eRgXsKxQ7+S9FSqNT7XYaTT0I7a6E6vnrNf6gxG0QmU3kACMQCAHgdZeKgwGYEA)